# How to remove row from datagrid and an array

Tags: arrays, wpf, csv, datagrid

My datagrid in WPF app. displays csv file.I want to copy csv file to an array.Remove a string from array which is same as the selected row from datagrid (comparing indexes).In the end I display the string array in second datagrid.

```
//Storing csv file in string array
var filePath = "csvFile.csv";
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while (!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        int selectedIndex =int.Parse(dgData.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        string strResult = file.ReadToEnd();
        string[] result = strResult.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        List<string> list = new List<string>(result);
        list.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
        foreach (string item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        dgtest.ItemsSource = list;
    } 
    file.Close();
}
```

I would appreciate correcting my code.At the moment I have an error stating:

> Index is out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are complicating things. Try something like this:

```
const string FilePath = "csvFile.csv";
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)?.ToList();
int selectedIndex = dgData.SelectedIndex;
if (lines != null && selectedIndex > 0 && lines.Count > selectedIndex)
    lines.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
dgtest.ItemsSource = lines;
```

Comment: Thanks @mm8 .But still I'm getting same error: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException.Index was out of range.`

Comment: I'm getting this error once I select the datagrid row and press "Remove" button  (in that event I placed your code).How can I check what is the value of selected row in datagrid?

Comment: I found the issue : Before your code I had a code to remove the selected line from datagrid itself so the value of selected index was '-1'.I Shifted those two codes and it works now.Except that as a result in dgtest I'm getting a list of lenghts (integers).

Comment: The csv file contains a columns with text strings mainly.That csv file is converted to list.

Comment: @Aga: Then you need to decide which columns to display and create such a data object. But please ask a new question if you have another issue. This question was about how to remove a row.